# PHPmailer - not getting read receipt

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPmailer (simple mail) to send out the emails. I have added headers since I want a read receipt of emal.
here is my code.

```
define(ADMINMAIL, 'test1@gmail.com');

try{
    $mail  = new PHPMailer(); 
    $ConfirmReadingTo = 'kendreparesh@gmail.com';

    $msPriority = 1;
    $mail->AddAddress('xyz@gmail.com', 'Mr XYZ');

    $mail->AddCustomHeader( 'X-pmrqc: 1' );
    $mail->AddReplyTo(ADMINMAIL,"Admin");
    $mail->SetFrom(ADMINMAIL, 'Admin');

    $mail->FromName = "Support Team<".ADMINMAIL.">";
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: $msPriority" );
    $mail->AddCustomHeader("Priority: $msPriority" );
    $mail->addCustomHeader("Return-Receipt-To: $ConfirmReadingTo");
    $mail->addCustomHeader("X-Confirm-Reading-To: $ConfirmReadingTo");
    $mail->addCustomHeader("Disposition-notification-to: $ConfirmReadingTo");
    $mail->ConfirmReadingTo = 'kendreparesh@gmail.com';
    $mail->WordWrap = 200;
    $mail->Encoding = "8bit";
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = "Subject line ";
    $mail->MsgHTML("This is email body");
    $mail->Send(); 

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<br/>".$e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

If you can see I have tried all the way to request read receipt, but NO LUCK :(

One more thing, the emails targeted to my company address never get received, Not even in Junk or Spam folder.

Please advice, what I have to do?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe the receiver just don't send those emails? There's no way to force sending confirmation emails, since it's the clients' software that actually does this. Also, maybe the 'onemorthing' is more of an extra question?

Comment: For testing I have used one of my email as a receiver of this email, but system is not asking about read receipt. since I am not able to test this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("Disposition-Notification-To: $ConfirmReadingTo");
```

works for me! note the capitals